# I'm trying to update with "sudo apt update" on ubuntu 22.04.1 but i'm getting errors. Can someone help me?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, 22.04

E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. It is held by process 1374 (packagekitd)

N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.

E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/

Comment: You've not provided specific details as to your system  (Desktop? Server? etc) but check for another process that was started & is waiting patiently for a user response (*thus also holding up your current attempt*)

Comment: @guiverc thanks. This answer my question and so helpfull. Btw I'm new on Linux especially Ubuntu. Thanks a lot.